# Static site set up with Rake gem. How do you add New Relic's yml file correctly?

Tags: heroku, rack, newrelic

I currently have a static website that deploys to Heroku via a Rack app.  Here is what my rack file looks like :

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/javascript", "/css", "/favicon.ico"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

I downloaded a config file from New Relic's site, but now I need to implement New Relic. Does anyone know what I need to change in my Rack file from the yml file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try just including the the yml file in the root path of your project.

Answer (score 1):

New Relic is not setup to handle static applications at this point.